# JavaScript scope pitfall with Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have an array B contains words like this

B = ['hello', 'love', 'peace']

I am trying to create a Promise array P:

```js
for(var i = 0; i<B.length; i++){
        var line = B[i];
        var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(line)},2000
            );
        })
        P.push(p);
    }

    Promise.all(P).then(function(data){
        console.log('data',data);
    })
```

I expect array **data** will equal ['hello', 'love', 'peace'] but actually data = ['peace', 'peace', 'peace']

I read some posts about JavaScript scope pitfall but still can't figure out how to fix my code.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you created a very peaceful promise. Jokes aside, besides using `let` you should really shift `line` into the `Promise`'s executor scope as Timosta recommended. You don't need a closure here, because `line` is just an auxiliary variable, which doesn't need to exist in the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use es6, you code may be like this

```js
let B = ['hello', 'love', 'peace'];

let P = [];

for(var i = 0; i<B.length; i++){
 let line = B[i];
 let p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
   setTimeout(function(){
     resolve(line)
   },2000);
 })
 P.push(p);
}

Promise.all(P).then(function(data){
 console.log('data',data);
})
```

if you use the es5, you should `var line = B[i];` in function p

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain for me the reason why my code doesn't work?

Comment: The difference is scoping. var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block (both are global if outside any block), which can be smaller than a function block.

Answer (score 1):

If you move the `line` initialization into the function scope of the promise callback, the different iterations will not affect each other:

```js
B = ['hello', 'love', 'peace'];
P = [];

for (var i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var line = B[i];
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(line)
        }, 2000);
    })
    P.push(p);
}

Promise.all(P).then(function(data) {
    console.log('data', data);
})

/*
data [
  "hello",
  "love",
  "peace"
]
*/
```

**[Some reading material on JavaScript closures and block vs. function scope.](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch3.md)**

Answer (score 0):

move the line inatialization inside promise

```
var B= ['hello', 'love', 'peace'] ;
  var P = [] ;
   for(var i = 0; i<B.length; i++){

        var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
           var line = B[i];
            setTimeout(function(){
                resolve(line)},2000
            );
        })
        P.push(p);
    }

    Promise.all(P).then(function(data){
        console.log('data',data);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `var` declarations are *hoisted* in JavaScript to the top of the nearest enclosing function block, or to the top of the file. This means that:

```
for (/* some loop */) {
  var line = someValue();
}
```

is actually translated into:

```
var line;
for (/* some loop */) {
  line = someValue();
}
```

You either need to move the `var` binding inside your `new Promise` closure or use an ES2015+ block binding (`let` or `const`)

```js
var words = ['hello', 'love', 'peace'];
var promises = [];
for (let word of words) {
  let letBinding = word;  // ES2015+
  const constBinding = word;  // ES2015+
  var varBinding = word;  // ES3+
  var p = new Promise(resolve => {
    var closureBinding = word;  // ES3+
    setTimeout(() =>
      resolve({
        varBinding,
        closureBinding,
        letBinding,
        constBinding,
      }),
      200
    );
  })
  promises.push(p);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(data => console.log('data:', data));
```

This logs out (after 200ms):

```
data: [
  {
    "varBinding": "peace",
    "closureBinding": "hello",
    "letBinding": "hello",
    "constBinding": "hello"
  },
  {
    "varBinding": "peace",
    "closureBinding": "love",
    "letBinding": "love",
    "constBinding": "love"
  },
  {
    "varBinding": "peace",
    "closureBinding": "peace",
    "letBinding": "peace",
    "constBinding": "peace"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other es6 answers take advantage of `let` having special scoping rules in `for` loops.

Just use `let` in the for loop statement (try to run it):

```js
var B = ['hello', 'love', 'peace'], P = [];

for(let i = 0; i<B.length; i++){
    var p = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(B[i])));
    P.push(p);
}

Promise.all(P).then(data => console.log(data)); // hello,love,peace
```

In es6, `let` instantiates a different `i` in each loop. This was done specifically to address this pitfall.

(The pitfall being that a single common `i` in the loop would have incremented to its final value by the time the three callbacks given to `setTimeout` access it seconds later).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Promise.all(
  ['hello', 'love',  'peace'].map(Promise.resolve.bind(Promise)))
.then(console.log.bind(console))
```

or with es7 bind syntax:

```
Promise.all(['hello', 'love', 'peace'].map(::Promise.resolve)).then(::console.log)
```